# Angularjs cannot bind to ngModel

Tags: angularjs

> I have used free angular coreui templates ,when i  bind data it throw
>   me an error
>   Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("
>                       ][(ngModel)]="username" autocomplete="username" required>
>                     
>                     <"): ng:///AppModule/LoginComponent.html@15:99
>   login.component.html

```
  <div class="app-body">
      <main class="main d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
              <div class="card-group">
                <div class="card p-4">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <form>
                      <h1>Login</h1>
                      <p class="text-muted">Sign In to your account</p>
                      <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" **[(ngModel)]="username"autocomplete="username" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group mb-4">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"  autocomplete="current-password" [(ngModel)]="password" required >
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary px-4" (click)checkLogin()>Login</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 text-right">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-link px-0">Forgot password?</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card text-white bg-primary py-5 d-md-down-none" style="width:44%">
                  <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <div>
                      <h2>Sign up</h2>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active mt-3">Register Now!</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing ** from before the ngModel in line 16. Like this,

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" [(ngModel)]="username"autocomplete="username" required>
```

Still if its does not work, bind the value using [value] like this.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" [(value)]="username"autocomplete="username" required>
```